# How to convert location module data to geofield?

Tags: google-maps, javascript, location

I need to switch my mapping implementation from Gmap to OpenLayers. I have a site with 1000+ users that already have data stored with the location module, and user locations. Is there an easy way to transfer the address/location to geofield?

Comment: [There is an issue about that in queue](https://www.drupal.org/node/1596576), abandoned for years. If you will solve this, don't forget to mention your solution there.

Comment: I'll update when this works, but I'm trying the laborious route export the users locations to the csv, configure address field and geofield, spitting the data back with feeds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I haven't found a way to convert it, but I did do the following.

1. Update content with Addressfield and Geofield
2. Set geofield to code from addressfield
3. used views data export to export the data
4. used feeds to spit the data into addressfield.

This basically met my requirements, pretty laborious and had to do a lot of data integrity checking, but it did what I wanted it to do.

Just as a heads up, Addressfield is very specific with it's term, which are internationalized. The fields you have to map have different field names, and different requires fields for each country, so be cautious with the spelling and fulfilling all the required fields. You can use Feeds Tamper if it's all single-country data. Just for example here are a few:

1. Province = Administrative area
2. Street = Thoroughfare
3. City = Locality